Trying to display a 3d model in a react app using Autodesk Forge but getting error 400
i have a 3d model here:
https://docs.b360.autodesk.com/projects/[project-id]/folders/urn:folder_urn_here/thumbnail/viewer/items/urn:item_urn_here
I want to display the 3d model in the React app,
This is the code:

import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { getForgeToken } from '../../helpers/axios/Get';
import axios from 'axios';


/* global Autodesk */ // eslint-disable-line

const ForgeViewer = ({ urn }) => {
    const viewerDiv = useRef(null);
    const viewerRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const initializeViewer = async () => {
            try {
                const { token, expires_in } = await getForgeToken();

                const options = {
                    env: 'AutodeskProduction',
                    api: 'streamingV2',  // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'streamingV2_EU'
                    getAccessToken: (onTokenReady) => {
                        console.log('Token:', token);
                        console.log('Expires In:', expires_in);
                        onTokenReady(token, expires_in);
                    },
                };

                console.log('Options:', options);
                if (window.Autodesk) {
                    console.log('Autodesk namespace is available');
                    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
                        console.log('Autodesk Initialized');
                        const config = {
                            'startOnInitialize': false,
                            'theme': 'light-theme'
                        };
                        const viewerElement = document.getElementById('forge-viewer');

                        const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(viewerElement, config);
                        viewerRef.current = viewer; // Store the viewer instance in the ref
                        console.log('Viewer:', viewer);
                        viewer.start();
                        console.log('Viewer started');

                        const urlSafeURN = Autodesk.Viewing.toUrlSafeBase64(urn);
                        console.log('URL Safe URN:', urlSafeURN);
                        const documentId = `urn:${urlSafeURN}`;
                        console.log('Document ID:', documentId);

                        // The following line makes a GET request with error 400
                        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
                    }, (error) => {
                        console.error('Error initializing Autodesk', error);
                    });
                } else {
                    console.error('Autodesk namespace is not available');
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error initializing viewer: ', error);
            }
        };

        initializeViewer();

        return () => {
            if (viewerRef.current) {
                viewerRef.current.finish();
            }
        };
    }, [urn]);

    function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
        console.log('Document loaded successfully:', doc);
        const rootItem = doc.getRoot();
        const geometryItems = rootItem.search({ type: 'geometry', role: '3d' });

        if (geometryItems.length > 0) {
            const viewer = viewerRef.current;
            viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, geometryItems[0], {
                keepCurrentModels: true
            });
            console.log('Model loaded successfully.');
        } else {
            console.error('No 3D geometry found in the document.');
        }
    }

    function onDocumentLoadFailure(errCode, errMsg) {
        console.error(`Failed to load manifest [${errCode}] ${errMsg}`);
    }

    return (
        <div id="forge-viewer" style={{ height: '100vh' }} ref={viewerDiv} />
    );
};

export default ForgeViewer;



the above component is used like this:
            <ForgeViewer urn={'adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:sjdiajsdpoijaspodijspoia'} />

getting this error in the console:

and this error in the Network tab:
Request URL: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/YWRzay53aXBwcm9kOmRtLmxpbmVhZ2U6MTgwdnhhVTZUSmV3UEhqc2MzQndRQQ/manifest
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Remote Address: 34.160.78.217:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

same error when i call this:
axios.get(`https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/${urlSafeURN}/manifest`, {
                            headers: {
                                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                            }
                        })
                            .then((response) => {
                                console.log('Manifest:', response.data);
                            })
                            .catch((error) => {
                                console.error('Error getting manifest:', error);
                            });



Hi,
I've reproduced the issue. The following lines seem unnecessary:
`urlSafeURN = Autodesk.Viewing.toUrlSafeBase64(urn);
documentId = urn:${urlSafeURN};`
Try using "urn" value directly, for example:
`let urn = "dXJvOjfkx5dma1JuEAI7czpvry5vgmplY3Q6Z2FhjYBssjSzYXSvS2Znd29kc2N3ZzZ1bmSqZ2lrdWJtdmJ0M2huc2k3aGlhdmp1LWJhc2ljLFFwcT9NYWluRmlsZS5ydnQ";
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load('urn:' + urn, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);`
It may be worth attempting this to see if it helps resolve the issue.
